# Firefox loses connection

Tags: windows-7, firefox

I am using Firefox 3.5.2 and it normally works fine but then randomly it will lose connection for a few minutes, just stalling and acting as though the page is loading. I can still use Chrome and IE but FF just sits there without doing anything, not even showing the 404 or connection timeout page.

Does anyone else have this problem and do they have a solution?

Comment: Read this also , this  might be helpful http://support.mozilla.com/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?locale=gl&comments_parentId=32024&forumId=1

Comment: That probably is the answer. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a new profile, it could be a corrupt file in there, make sure you back up your bookmarks before messing around with the profile in case you lose them. This site shows you how to create a new profile.

To Check about profile : **http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles**

Comment: Where can i make a new profile?

Comment: http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles

Comment: is this really the solution?!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have bad connection. Most likely some packets gets lost on the way and webserver never gets the request and browser keeps waiting for an answer which will never be sent. A simple fix is F5 (Refresh).

You can check if this really is the problem by pinging hostname of that webserver over a longer time (2-10 mins) and checking how many packets are lost.

To do that just type this into command-line:

```
ping -t mywebhost.com
```

You can stop pinging and check statistics by pressing CTRL + C .

EDIT:
Still it's strange since it should affect all browsers. Anyhow try refreshing the page in FF or opening it in new tab. If it works then, then it's probably packet loss as I explained above.

Also I don't see how corrupt files could cause something like that.

Comment: It's not that because the same pages would load in Chrome and all of the tabs i had open wouldn't load.

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to the number of temporary files stored. Try running CCleaner (from ccleaner.com)  Be sure to click the applications tab and uncheck 'cookies' for convenience sake.